# audio from speaker not working

Tags: sound, audio-jack

i have Realtek audio chip ALC1220 in my MSI gp63 with GTX 1060. The speaker doesn't produce any sound; but, if I plug my earphones in, the earphones work fine.

I have tried to purge and reinstall alsamixer and have played with the audio in alsamixer to no avail.

I have tried installing Pulse Audio Volume Control, but nothing changes alsamixer shows I am using HDA intel PCH.

Answer (score 0):

`alsamixer` and `pulseaudio` actually conflict with each other. But you cannot delete any of them since they are all required by Ubuntu

PulseAudio “official” website suggested that [PulseAudio usually overwrites the ALSA settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Pulse_overwrites_ALSA_settings).

`PulseAudio` has problems in recognizing the audio device, the user has to manually configure it by editing the `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf` file.

1: Open terminal and type

```
sudo nano /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf
```

2: Change

```
[Element Desktop Speaker]
switch = off
volume = off
```

to

```
[Element Desktop Speaker]
switch = on
volume = on
```

This solution works because every time `pulseaudio` runs it uses this file to generate settings for `analog-output-speaker` profile which overwrites the settings set in `alsamixer`.

Comment: it did nothing ....except now when i press vol change combo key it shows the volume of headphone being changed....and then i put my real headphone in and plug it out then vol change key shows change happening to  Digital output (s/pdif)....also the sound settings shows that there is only digital output (s/pdif) ....while before there was speaker in there tooo

Comment: edit:-i forgot to add this recent discovery before i applied your changes ....when i increase the volume of the headphone from the alsamixer the sound from speaker started to play .